# Is it possible to draw line between the annotations in mkmap by using cocos2d in single view application?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Hai am developing a vehicle tracking iOS app using xcode 4.5. For that I need to draw lines between annotation points. for that can I use cocos2d to draw lines? kindly guide me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: yes It's possible.. I have already done in my app.. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anti-kidnap-baby-safety-baby/id820906607?mt=8

Comment: @Joge Thank you.. Could you please advice me how to do this with some sample code or some related tutorial..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Below is the sample code

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[2];
    coordinates[0] = currentLocation.coordinate;
    coordinates[1] = targetLocation.coordinate;


    //add new overlay
    MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:2];
    [navigationMapView addOverlay:polyLine];
```